# Using a query in a conditional statement in PLSQL?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Can I do something like the following in PLSQL?

```
if (some_query) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Your query returned at least 1 row.');
else
    dbms_output.put_line('Your query returned no rows.');
end if;
```

My use case is I want to check if a value already exists in my database.  If the value already exists then I will do something different than if the value doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you a checking for existence of a record, then you can select COUNT(*) from the source table based on the key as it will always return a value you can check:

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> DECLARE
  2      v_check NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4      SELECT COUNT(*)
  5      INTO v_check
  6      FROM DUAL
  7      WHERE DUMMY = 'X'
  8      AND ROWNUM = 1;
  9
 10      if (v_check = 0) then
 11          dbms_output.put_line('Your query returned no rows.');
 12      else
 13          dbms_output.put_line('Your query returned at least 1 row.');
 14      end if;
 15  END;
 16  /
Your query returned at least 1 row.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Explain the part about rownum = 1? Does this improve the speed for a query which might otherwise count a million rows? Or is it just a nice way of getting a boolean value which is either 1 or 0?

Comment: @Buttons840 Correct. If you are searching for the existence of a non-key field then cut the query off when the first record satisfying the where clause is found. The code logic is checking for the 0 case, so the actual count is not used.

Comment: @Buttons840 Exactly! My answer is evaluated from left to right. The first part of your OR is Correct ;)

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to do something like

```
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
    INTO l_foo
    FROM dual
   WHERE EXISTS (<<some query>>);

  dbms_output.put_line( 'Your query returned at least 1 row' );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Your query returned 0 rows' );
END;
```

If the query isn't too expensive, it will be almost as efficient and probably a bit easier to maintain if you do something simpler

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO l_foo
  FROM (<<some query>>)
 WHERE rownum = 1;

IF( l_foo = 1 )
THEN
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Your query returned at least row.' );
ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Your query returned 0 rows.' );
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same, no. But there are several ways you can fake it:

If you only need to do one thing do it inside an implicit cursor that confirms whether your value exists.

```
for i in ( some_query ) loop

   do_something;

end loop;
```

You can also set a value in here and use it in an `if`

```
for i in ( some_query ) loop

   result := True;

end loop;

if result then
   do_something;
else
   do_something_else;
end if;
```

Or you can use an explicit cursor and catch the `no_data_found` error that'll be raised

```
declare

  cursor c_blah is
   select my_value
     from my_table
    where id = my_id
          ;

  my_value varchar2(4000);

begin

  open c_blah(my_id);
  fetch c_blah into my_value;
  close c_blah;

  do_something;

  exception when no_data_found then
     do_something_else;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your use case behaves identically whether the query returns one row or a thousand, use `EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE
    l_dummy     VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
    SELECT NULL
    INTO   l_dummy
    FROM   DUAL
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM   <some_query>);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your query returned at least one row.');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your query returned no rows.');
END;
```